# Prevent page to rebuild using bottom navigation in flutter

Tags: flutter, riverpod, google-maps-flutter

Is there a way to prevent a page from being rebuilt when using bottom navigation bar in Flutter?

I have a `bottomNavigationBar` with 3 items. There are some `riverpod` providers running for the different pages. I need the first page to not rebuild when I navigate to other pages because there are providers behind it running some tasks that should not be aborted such that when I return to the page, the state should already be updated.
Basically I have a google map (https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) that is listening to a position stream and being updated. I would love for the map to not reload every time I return to the first page.

Or is bottom navigation not the best option for this use case?

Comment: Maybe you just need to change `@riverpod` to `@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)`?

Comment: Hi @DhafinRayhan, I will try that and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it by using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`  as explained in this [post](https://blog.canopas.com/how-to-maintain-the-state-of-bottomnavigationbar-across-tabs-528b3699f78b)